# Invoke Backing bean method from JavaScript + JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, javabeans

I want to invoke backing bean method from javascript function in JSF. Please could you guide me how to achive this.

Regards,
Ravi Krish

Answer (score 2):

Since, Backing bean method id Server side so you need to make request to server better way for your case would be

1. [Richfaces JSFunction](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html) , [Live Demo Link](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jsFunction.jsf?c=jsFunction&tab=usage)
2. [Ajax4JSF](https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/)

Comment: Upvoting requires at least 15 rep. The OP has currently only one. Give his question a upvote so that he at least earns 5 rep and has yet only 10 to go :)

Comment: :) Not a bad choice, But If its the case you should have given :) So let me wait until he accept this as answer.

Comment: Another option to consider could be PrimeFaces and it's remote command http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf