# JSF 2.0 AJAX: Call a bean method from javascript with jsf.ajax.request (or some other way)

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

Some background: I am building a custom JSF component. The component is basically a text editor and it should have a "Save" -button for saving the content string of the editor. As I am using the [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) library, I need to fetch the content (string) from the editor with javascript and send that to the server. Therefore, in this case I cannot use XML-based JS invocation such as `f:ajax`.

The question: I was planning to send the string with `jsf.ajax.request`, but it doesn't directly support calling methods on beans. How can I invoke a method in a bean with JSF in AJAX manner?

There at least two ways to get around this:

- Include a hidden form to page with hidden inputfield. Update that inputfield from javascript and then call jsf.ajax.request to post that form. Custom actions can be invoced in the property's getter or setter if needed.
- Do the request with raw `XMLHttpRequest` (or maybe with help from some other JS library). Create a servlet and call that.

Both ways are clumsy and the latter also breaks out of JSF scope.

Am I missing something? How do you do these?

There is a [quite similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690461/jsf-2-0-ajax-jsf-ajax-request-to-call-method-not-only-rerender-an-area-of-page), but the answers given only refer to XML-based AJAX invocations. There is also [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581499/invoke-backing-bean-method-from-javascript-jsf), but that refers to XML-based AJAX calls as well.

Comment: How exactly are you building it? As `UIComponent` or as `<ui:composition>` or `<composite:implementation>`?

Comment: This one is built simply on top of `ui:composition`. Basically I have a `textarea` there, that I initialize with JS invocation within `script` element. I also have a `commandButton` that should work as the Save button. Why, does it matter if I'm using composite components or UIComponents?

Comment: With `UIComponent` you could just extend `UIInput` and JSF will take care about updating the model values. But after thinking once more, that's of course tricky when it concerns a 3rd party HTML/CSS/JS based editor. Have you considered a fullworthy JSF component? E.g. [PrimeFaces `p:editor`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf).

Comment: Good point for extending `UIInput`, but you are probably right that in this case that's not an really option. I did a quick search about existing components and also found `p:editor`. Unfortunately, none of the existing componenets fits our needs so I had to take this route.

Comment: [There is a way to call JSF Backing Bean method from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619906/calling-managed-bean-method-from-javascript)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I couldn't find out how to call beans direcly with javascript, but here is a hack around calling f:ajax-declaration from javascript:

1) Create a hidden form with fields for all the data that you want to send to the server. Include a h:commandButton as well:

```
<h:form id="hiddenForm" style="display: none;">
    <h:inputHidden id="someData" value="#{someBean.someData}" />
    <h:commandButton id="invisibleClickTarget">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{someBean.myCoolActionOnServer()}" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

As usual, `listener` attribute, `#{someBean.myCoolActionOnServer()}` in this case, refers to the method that you want to execute on the server.

2) In some other button use `onclick` to call for your special javascript AND click the trigger-button via javascript:

```
<h:commandButton value="Click me" onclick="populateTheForm('hiddenForm'); document.getElementById('hiddenForm:invisibleClickTarget').click(); return false;" />
```

`populateTheForm()` should actually fill the data into hiddenForm's fields.

This is a simplification of my case but should work. Still looking for more conventient approach, though.

Comment: As an alternative you could also just leave away the `<h:commandButton>` and use `<f:ajax>` inside `<h:inputHidden>` which get executed on `change` event. That's less code.

Comment: Yeah, that should work if user wants to transfer just one field (well, in this case I do). With multiple fields within the form, I guess that might trigger unwanted behavior, with AJAX call launching before rest of the fields could be updated.

Comment: ...unless one puts that `f:ajax` for the field that is updated last. Yup, that would do the trick. Thanks for your suggestions once again, BalusC.

Comment: I tried this by putting the `f:ajax` directly inside `h:inputHidden`. The result is '<f:ajax> Unable to attach <f:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent'. So this is not possible.

Comment: There is a minor problem with your code: You are closing the `h:commandButton` in the same line as you are opening it...

Comment: @unwichtich Indeed, fixed the typo, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I did this task several times. Yo don't need multiply hidden fiels. You can use only one hidden field, convert all input values to JSON object via JSON.stringify and set into this field. On the server side - deserialize JSON object (there are many Java libs for that) to an Java class. That's all.

Comment: That's good to know, although what do you benefit from that? Having multiple fields JSF does conversions/validations automatically, your code is more statically typed (though the approach still sucks). Care to open up a bit?