# Doing AJAX with JSF 2.0 without using action listeners

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm new to JSF. I am using JSF 2.0.

I'd like to be able to use scripts that use ajax in a classical way, not going through JSF's f:ajax tag.

However, I know that it's easy to mess up with the application's state if you go around JSF features too much. Has anyone done this before? Any ideas on how it should be done? Suggestions and existing frameworks that can help me do this are both valid answers.

Comment: why you don't like the standard way?...

Comment: Because the standard way doesnt let you use AJAX if there is no user action, button clicked, text entered, etc. If there was support for custom javascript events, I would be happy to use the standard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [JSF 2.0 AJAX: Call a bean method from javascript with jsf.ajax.request (or some other way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710908/jsf-2-0-ajax-call-a-bean-method-from-javascript-with-jsf-ajax-request-or-some-o) for a way of doing going around JSF's restrictive AJAX behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This goes totally beyond the nature of a component based MVC framework. This is going to bite you. Just don't use JSF then. Use an action based MVC framework instead. E.g. Stripes, Spring MVC, etc.