# JSF to call managed bean method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

Is there any way to call a managed bean method from JavaScript?

I have a link in a datatable which should go to a document repository for the corresponding tender. Please check the screenshot. But the datatable, inside a panel, which is inside a layout and so the link is not diverting the page to the required path. So I am trying to call a JavaScript from the link which in turn call a method from managed bean which will return to the required page. I have tried to hide a button and make it submit on click of the link. But its not working.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the specifications of the framework you are using ?

Comment: Duplicate: [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710908/jsf-2-0-ajax-call-a-bean-method-from-javascript-with-jsf-ajax-request-or-some)

Comment: Using primefaces,jsf 2.0, and this may be a duplicate question. But the answer which they have given seems not working for me. Cant we simply call a managed bean method in javascript

Comment: Have you tried using [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate to require page you need to pass the required information in f:param (e.g In your case pass the unique id or number or may be tender number something )and the call the ManagedBean method on it.

Comment: <p:commandLink id="submitButton" actionListener="#{docManagedBean.viewDocs(action)}" 
                                                     value="View Docs"> 
                                 <f:param name="tenderId" value="#{tenderinfo.tenderId}"  />
                                     </p:commandLink>Its getting diverted to the proper page. Now i want to get the id in my managed bean and display documents related to the ID . so what should i do.

Comment: Create on util class
public class Utils {
 private static Utils dnbUtils;
 private Utils(){}
 
 public static Utils getInstance() {
  if(dnbUtils == null){
   dnbUtils = new Utils();
  }
  return dnbUtils;
 }
 
 public String getRequestParam(String parameterName) {
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  return (String)context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(parameterName);
 }
 
 }
 
 
Managed Bean Code
String value=Utils.getInstance().getRequestParam("name_of_f:param");
logger.info(""+value);

Comment: ok , i used u r code and its working. I did FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("tenderId");which gives me the required tender Id. But still i dont understand what is this Utils class. But Thanks .

Comment: and i have not used the Utils class at all

Comment: Basically Utils class is just a Utility class where we can specify JSF related functionality.Instead of implementing duplicate code in our ManagedBean we use to specify the functionlity in Utils class & simply create instance of the class and then access the method in ManagedBean.

Answer (score 0):

OK finally I got it .

In command link if I use action its not diverting. But I changed it to actionListener and it works.

```
 <p:commandLink id="submitButton" actionListener="#{docManagedBean.viewDocs(action)}" 
                                                     value="View Docs">

                                     </p:commandLink>
```

and my Managed Bean method

```
 public void viewDocs(ActionEvent action) throws IOException{
 FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/Proj-war/faces" +      "/DocumentRepositary/documentsView" + ".xhtml");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple `<h:link>` if all you want is to perform navigation on clicking? And you can set `<f:param>` to inform of the tender id or other unique values within the link. As your tender search results are located within `<ui:repeat>`, as I suppose, just add simple links to navigate to the tender docs. My point of view is that making a redirect from an action listener method is actually a big problem in design. Usage of command buttons is acceptable if you want to perform some operations on the page or before viewing the target page.

Simple example: part of search.xhtml:

```
<ui:repeat var="tender" value="#{tenderBean.tenders}">
    <!-- UI part of table -->
    <h:link value="View tender docs"utcome="path/to/tender/docs/viewDocs.xhtml">
        <f:param name="tenderId" value="#{tender.id}" />
    </h:link>
</ui:repeat>
```

Simple example continued: part of viewDocs.xhtml:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="tenderId" value="#{tenderDocsBean.tenderId}" required="true" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{tenderDocsBean.loadTenderDocs}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id) on usage of `<f:viewParam>`.

Comment: since i am using primefaces , i am not sure whether is that the reason.

Comment: if i use h:link its displaying as  a label and not as a link. and as for view docs .xhtml , i dont want to get the value in jsf. but i want the value in my java managed bean

Comment: please also look at this code '<p:commandLink id="submitButton" actionListener="#{docManagedBean.viewDocs(action)}" value="View Docs"> <f:param name="tenderId" value="#{tenderinfo.tenderId}" /> </p:commandLink>Its getting diverted to the proper page. Now i want to get the id in my managed bean and display documents related to the ID for which i have a query in MBean. so what should i do.'

Comment: I wouldn't use button in your situation because all you want to do is perform navigation, as I stated in my answer. I think that get request is suitable in this case because user will be able to derive the tender he is viewing in the url. If you want to load a page on button click then you might use the following code: `<p:commandButton action="path/to/tender/docs/viewDocs.xhtml"> <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{tenderinfo.tenderId}" value="#{tender.id}"/> </p:commnandButton>`. This will preset the value of a needed bean and make it available during view docs page load.

Comment: And don't forget to add ajax="false" to properties of commandButton.